# How should I update a time? new Date or setInverval?

Tags: javascript, date, object, time, intervals

I am updating a clock once every second, the time comes from a `new Date` object, but I am wondering if it is better to simply add upon an initial time with `setInterval` or to create a `new Date` every second and work with that object to update the time.

They both work, but I am wondering if it is responsible to be creating a new object every second, since I am sure the `setInterval()` method would use a considerably smaller amount of resources since three functions are executed when getting time. (`.getHours()`, `.getMinutes()`, `.getSeconds()`)

I can see an advantage in having it use a `new Date` object, as I assume it would change when the systems time changes (changing timezone or daylight savings adjustments).

So is it more efficient to use `setInverval()` or would it use just as many resources as creating a `new Date` object each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval(function myFunc(){}, 1000)` does not guarantee, that `myFunc` will be called every second.  In fact, the inteval can vary heavily. For example, in Chrome, if you change tab, the interval will slow down a lot, until you return to the initial tab.
So keep using `new Date()`.
See http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 0):

Use this , it will help you, in order to display the time at only once after your page getting loaded you simply can use the new Date() and the getHours(),getMinutes,getSeconds function. In order to display the updated time without making the page to refresh you need to use both setInterval(), and new date() functionalities together.you need to use new date() inside set interval because, if you add any alert in side you code then it will not pause your time updation.

```js
function pad(str, max) {

  return ((str.length < max) ? pad("0" + str, max) : str);
}
var d;
setInterval(function myFunc() {
  d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("date").innerText = (pad(d.getHours().toString(), 2) + ":" + pad(d.getMinutes().toString(), 2) + ":" + pad(d.getSeconds().toString(), 2));
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: May i know the reason for your comment @RobG

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.